# What would cause an &nbsp; to turn into a unicode character?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got some documents on my website which users can edit via  a rich text editor and then save them (to the DB) and print them. Some users are experiencing an issue (only happening on the live site) where some of the characters are getting screwed up. I've checked the DB, and the funny characters are in the DB, so it's not a display issue. It either happens when they save the document (submit the form on the site) or they've put something weird in there or their browser changed some of the characters.

The character that keeps appearing everywhere is `Â` . It's an accented A followed by a space. Looking at the source HTML, it appears that the affected documents had all their `&nbsp;`'s converted. But whenever I try it, they come out fine.

What would cause an `&nbsp;` to turn into a unicode character, but only in limited cases?

Comment: You are not handling encodings correctly. See [Handling Unicode in a Webapp](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) and troubleshoot your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Misinterpreting the UTF-8 encoding as Latin-1 will cause this.

```
>>> u'\xa0'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
u'\xc2\xa0'
>>> print u'\xa0*'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
Â *
```